# What is the meaning and etymology of "ruthless?"

Tags: meaning, etymology

A "standard" definition is something like "cruel," or "remorseless."

But what does this have to do with "ruth" (or lack thereof)? Is this a reference to a kind person named Ruth?

Perhaps a clue may be found from the German *Rücksicht*, which translates literally into "back sight," or "looking back." Could it then be that a "ruthless" person is actually one who plows ahead, without "looking back" at what the consequences may be?

And how would this evolve into the "standard" definition?

Comment: Did you check http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=ruthless&searchmode=none

Comment: Be careful when trying to find cognate terms in other languages based on orthography.  In this case 'Rücksicht' has no relation to the word 'ruthless' other than the first consonant. There are patterns of sound changes that are common and predictable based on the articulation of sounds among other things.  You could get a good start on some of the basic concepts by from here: [Sound Change][1] and [Phonological Change][2].[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_change
  [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_change

Comment: @Mark T: I was doing what I call a "permutation analysis (searching possible permutations; the reference to Ruth was another example).Rücksichtlos is quite plausible in this regard. "No look back" could be construed as remorseless, if not cruel. But rue and "rueless" is the better root word.

Comment: @unreason: That's a good link. But it probably took the answer below to produce the "light bulb" moment in my head.

Comment: @TomAu   
Hi Tom, just wanted to let you know that the ["Italian Language & Usage"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language-usage) proposal has restarted. Since you committed to the previous proposal, maybe you are still interested. See you!
(I hope this comment is not considered as spam, if so I beg your pardon)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The meaning of *ruthless*, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, is:

> Feeling or showing no pity or compassion; pitiless, unsparing, merciless, remorseless.

The etymology is a thornier issue. For *ruthless*, the etymology provided is simply "ruth *n.* + -less *suffix.*" So, we turn to *ruth*:

> The quality of being compassionate; the feeling of sorrow for another; compassion, pity. Also with for.

Its etymology is:

> rue *v.* + -th *suffix*, perhaps after early Scandinavian (compare Old Icelandic *hryggð*).

*Rue* here means:

> To affect with sorrow or regret; to distress, grieve. Freq. with *it* as subject and clause as complement, and without *it* and with following clause as implicit subject. Now *arch*.

In the OED, the etymology for this word stretches to—I kid you not—five paragraphs. I'll give you the first of those, which contains most of the important information, I think:

> A merging of two distinct but closely related words from the same Germanic base: (i) an Old English strong verb of Class II (*hrēowan*), cognate with Old Frisian *riōwa*, *riouwa* (strong verb; West Frisian *rouwe*, *rouje*, weak), Middle Dutch *rouwen*, *rowen*, *ruwen*, *rauwen* (inflected both strong and weak; Dutch *rouwen*, weak), Old Saxon *hreuwan* (strong; Middle Low German *rǖwen*, *rūwen*, *rouwen*, weak), Old High German *hriuwan*, *riuwan* (strong; Middle High German *riuwen*, *rūwen*, strong, German *reuen*, weak); and, (ii) an Old English weak verb of Class II (*hrēowian*), cognate with Old Saxon *hriwōn*, *hrewōn*, Old High German *hriuwōn*, *riuwōn*; compare also (with different suffixes) Old High German *riuwēn* (weak Class III), and Old Icelandic *hryggva*, *hryggja* (weak Class I); further etymology uncertain: perhaps related to Sanskrit *karuṇa* pitiable, woeful. The diphthongal West Germanic stem forms do not reflect a Proto-Germanic diphthong, but rather show the result of the operation of Holtzmann's Law (compare the Old Icelandic form); this proves that the conjugation as a strong verb of Class II must be an analogical development in West Germanic. Compare also from the same Germanic base the adjectives Old English *hrēow*, Old Saxon *hriuwi*, Old Icelandic *hryggr*, all in sense ‘sad, sorrowful’.

The following paragraphs are even more technical, dealing with issues like strong and weak verbs in Old English and the decline of the Middle English diphthong *ēu*. Of particular note: none of them say anything about the name Ruth. Whether *ruth* and the name *Ruth* have a shared root I can't say for sure, but it seems to me that the *OED*'s etymology suggests against that hypothesis.

Comment: So the correct root word could be "rue," and "ruthless, would mean "rueless." Makes perfect sense.

Comment: +1 for having access (and using) better references.

Comment: @TomAu This is a very old question, but the _-th_ suffix is actually not that strange even in modern English. In this case, it’s added onto a verb stem, whereas in most words it’s added to an adjective, but it’s the same suffix. Very similar to _rue_, but used in a more synchronically transparent sense, is _true_, which forms an entirely parallel abstract noun too: ***truth***. So you can think of _ruthless_ as being to _rue_ what _truthless_ is to _true_. (_Truthless_ isn’t actually in normal use, but it’s completely transparent, so it’s still a fairly good parallel to draw on.)

Answer (score 9):

The etymology of *ruthless* doesn't have much to do with the Biblical Ruth. [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ruthless) has:

> early 14c., from reuthe "pity, compassion" (late 12c.), formed from reuwen "to rue" (see rue (v.)) on the model of true/truth, etc. Ruthful (early 13c.) has fallen from use since late 17c. except as a deliberate archaism

This does sound similar to the female name "Ruth", but in actuality "Ruth" and "ruthless" probably do not share a root. Again, from [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Ruth):

> fem. proper name, biblical ancestor of David, from Heb. Ruth, probably a contraction of reuth "companion, friend, fellow woman."

*Ruth* is an ancient Hebrew name, whereas *reuthe* (root of "ruthless") dates back only to the 12th century. It is possible, though I have not found conclusive evidence, that *reuthe* derives from *Ruth*--but this does not imply that *ruthless* directly derives from the name *Ruth*.

Comment: I have no special knowledge of comparative linguistics relevant to this one, but I rather suspect there's no causal connection at all between ME *ruthe/reuth* and the Hebrew name *Ruth* (which seems to simply mean "[female]companion" - implying nothing about such a person's attitudes).

Comment: But *reuthe*, meaning "pity, compassion," is an Old English word, whereas *reuth*, meaning "companion, friend, fellow woman," is Hebrew. Besides the fact that the definitions you've given don't seem particularly similar, English is part of the Germanic branch of the Indo-European language family, whereas Hebrew is part of the Semitic branch of the Afro-Asiatic family. Do you know of any evidence of a connection between the word and the name?

Comment: Er…I mean…what FumbleFingers said.

Comment: I find it unlikely (though possible) that _Ruth_ in Hebrew derives from _Reuth_, because it doesn't follow the usual contraction rules. It's hard to know for sure because the words are so old, but a (possibly) more likely derivation for _Ruth_ in Hebrew connects it to _Ruts_, which means _run_, distancing it even more from the Germanic-rooted _ruth_. My source is in Hebrew: http://www.hebrewetymology.com/.

Comment: Also, I minor correction: _reuth_ in Hebrew does not mean "_female_ companion". It means _companionship_, irrespective of sex or gender, even though the word itself is female, simply because all nouns in Hebrew have gender. The word has contractions for both a female companion and a male companion, and is used today more in the sense of _friendship_.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to see the centre of "ruthless" connected with the modern German noun Reue (remorse, regret), "ruth" is a noun with the ending -th as in warmth. We have the verb to rue sth (literary, dated) also in German be-reu-en.

So I would say words like "Rücksicht" or the Bible name Ruth are the wrong track.
"ruthless" means ohne Reue (without remorse).

A pity that etymonline doesn't give the connection to German Reue and bereuen. It would help understand the word ruthless better.

Answer (score 0):

I can also see a connection between *reuthe* and *ruth* in the Bible since the **Ruth** in the Bible showed compassion for her unhappy mother-in-law by staying with her and not deserting her by going back to her own people after her mother-in-law's husband and sons had died.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Thanks for your answer. An upvote to get you going.

Comment: Well, the Bible was written/composed/handed down a few thousand years ago. The split between Semitic and Germanic languages occurred probably more than 4000 years _before_ that, possibly as much as 20000 years earlier. It's possible but highly unlikely that the word "jumped over" from one language group to another. Also, whether Ruth showed compassion or behaved from some other motive is a question of interpretation, and not directly indicated in the text itself, which does not actually use any of the Hebrew words for _compassion_.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up here when searching for etymology of "ruthless" in context of english newspapers using it to describe german play against brazil yesterday. :-)

I would suggest some common source with german "ruchlos", a rather outdated but still known expression. It is linked to the as oldfashioned "anrüchig" or "verrucht".

This seems to be linked to smell (German: Ge-ruch) and to have some link to the smell that you acquire if you don't avoid to get in contact with rotten malodour matters.

OR: To german "Reue" from indg. khrewan, meaning not regretting smthg you do/have done. Nearest I could find in old english was "reccan" coming from german "rōk(j)an" (to care for smthg).

Preferably both have a common root.

Anyone able to verify or falsify this? It is only my wild guessing.

Btw: Sorry for me posting here by ruthlessly ignoring my pidging like english language command.

Answer (score -2):

Ruth may be the apocryphal character of the Moabite daughter-in-law of Naomi who refused to leave her mother-in-law when she was forced to return to Judea.  As a Moabite, Ruth would have been a target of scorn and hatred by the Jews.  However, knowning this, she remained the kind and attentive servant to her mother-in-law in this hostile social environment.  Her Name came to be synonomous with kindness.  Perhaps the addition of the suffix *-less* would come to denote a description of being without Ruth or without kindness; therefore a lack of pity and compassion.

Comment: It seems likely (as others have said) that *ruthless* cames from Scandinavian sources, and the Hebrew name *Ruth* is purely coincidental.  And you need to be careful using the word *apocryphal* in a Biblical context.

Comment: The Bible doesn't say anything about Ruth being kind or attentive. It says that she declared that she would follow Naomi anywhere she went. Compassion, pity, kindness, and attention are all subject to interpretation, as is the question of whether or not she would have been hated and whether the social environment would have been hostile. At least in Hebrew, her name is definitely _not_ synonymous with kindness, and most native Hebrew speakers will tell you that they don't know the origin of the word. They will not associate it with compassion.

Answer (score -5):

"R" denotes a moving out and away from an original source. "U" comes into play as the movement away from the source softens and transforms the original place, allowing for a shift in the observed truth. As this occurs, the ability to act from another source allows for a shift in the point of original interjection and holds a new vision. This shift lifts the point of focus, causing the original source to not occupy the same site. "The legend of rue lives on in playing cards, where the symbol for the suit of clubs is said to be modeled on a leaf of rue." Rue discourages fleas and other pests from being in the space occupied by people. It implies replacement and displacement, attributes of ruthless behaviors.

Comment: Weird, but interesting.