# What is the difference in connotation between "relentless" and "ruthless?"

Tags: word-choice, connotation

My understanding is that both words refer to a hard-charging "take no prisoners" approach to an issue.[Relentless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relentless) is defined as, "showing or promising no abatement of severity, activity, strength or pace," and [ruthless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruthless) as "having no pity."

My further understanding is that "relentless" is more "honorable" than "ruthless." Examples:

> In a "relentless" pursuit of her career, she stabbed people in the belly. 
>   In a "ruthless" pursuit of his career, he stabbed people in the back.

Is this the correct distinction? Are the words more similar than this? Or do I have the wrong connotation for one or both words?

**Edit1:** A commenter defined ruthless as "having no pity", and relentless was "showing or promising no abatement of severity, intensity, strength, or pace" or "oppressively constant; incessant" (respectively) using dictionary definitions. which corresponds with my own research. IMHO, the two definitions are synonymous. If that's not the case, I am genuinely confused. My understanding of the difference between the two is the "honorable" part cited in the previous paragraph. Is this, indeed, the case?

**Edit2:** In answer to the commenter's later comment, I believe that a person who is single-mindedly "relentless" also "shows no pity" (his definition of ruthless). That may be wrong of course, but that's part of the basis of my question.

**Edit3:** [This source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relentless) considers the two words synonyms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

“Relentless” has a connotation of persistence and not able to be easily stopped by physical challenges.

“Ruthless” has the connotation of not being stopped by moral or ethical considerations.

A hero who chases a villain no matter what is relentless; if s/he is willing to injure or kill innocent people to capture the villain, he or she is ruthless.

Comment: Correct. "ruthless" entails a sense of cruelty "relentless" lacks.

Comment: @Gustavson: The term that I would use is "dishonourable" rather than "cruel." If one administered a lethal injection to someone on death row, it would be cruel but not dishonourable.

Comment: @TomAu I agree with this answer. See also [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36933/what-is-the-meaning-and-etymology-of-ruthless) about *ruthless*. Regarding connotation, context matters a lot to both terms, though *ruthless* carries intrinsically a lack of compassion that *relentless* relies more heavily on its context to provide.

Answer (score 3):

Does a ruthless individual have to be relentless?

Relentless is a "to the ends of the earth" mentality.  Perhaps even a "completionist" while ruthlessness does not require such things.

Ruthless means a lack of compassion.

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote for a pretty good answer.